# What happens when you reach max Senate favour?

Tags: rome-total-war

I reached 9 favour points with the Senate (out of 10) and it sayed that they are thinking to declare me "Father of the Repiblic". Unfortunately, I ended up losing favour and couldn't find out myself.
**Does this mean that something special would happen at 10 favour points, like giving me direct control of Rome without the need of a civil war?**

Answer (score 2):

According to this link: [total war forum](http://www.twcenter.net/forums/showthread.php?472031-What-happen-when-roman-senate-floor-is-max-fufilled), when you max out senate favour, the senate might see you as a protector, or they fear you and thus they send you away on mission. Eventwise it is said, that nothing exceptional happens, only some higher chance of your family members getting into the senate.

"usually if your senate favor is full then best to watch your back as one of the other roman factions is surging and garnering huge popular support-- thus, the senate seeing yourself as a shield

other times it means the senate is starting to fear you-- thus, they will up the ante on giving you random missions away from rome and away from their fleeting power base

nothing happens, however, as far as triggering some kind of event-- however, you will probably have a better chance of your family members getting a senatorial position (and some more general cav bodyguards...)"